# How to run the code using AFL on terminal

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, testing, terminal

I have some of github that I am trying to run using AFL.
The code: https://github.com/karimmd/CScanner/tree/cfe7d08bf46b1eed0443f9e27bc089d68a830a45

I wanna run the project and find vulnerablities. I have put the github all files inside a folder `code` , so the file structure is CScanner-master/code/all the files here.
I am using this command on terminal :

```
   hemlatamahaur@Hemlatas-MacBook-Pro desktop % afl-fuzz -i CScanner-master -o code ./input-testcode.c
afl-fuzz 2.56b by <lcamtuf@google.com>
[+] You have 4 CPU cores and 2 runnable tasks (utilization: 50%).
[+] Try parallel jobs - see /usr/local/Cellar/afl-fuzz/2.57b/share/doc/afl/parallel_fuzzing.txt.
[*] Setting up output directories...
[+] Output directory exists but deemed OK to reuse.
[*] Deleting old session data...
[+] Output dir cleanup successful.
[*] Scanning 'CScanner-master'...
[+] No auto-generated dictionary tokens to reuse.
[*] Creating hard links for all input files...
[*] Validating target binary...

[-] PROGRAM ABORT : Program './input-testcode.c' not found or not executable
         Location : check_binary(), afl-fuzz.c:6873
```

It keep saying there is no file as input-testcode.c

I am new to AFL, so I might be doing it wrong. How do I run this code using AFL to find the vulnerabilities. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build your code using afl-clang first

afl-clang

`$ afl-clang input-testcode.c -o input-testcode` .

Then:

`$ afl-fuzz -i CScanner-master -o code ./input-testcode` .

I hope it works
Afl-fuzz works on the executable